# How to retain original file names within a zipped file when using zipAggregationStrategy

Tags: routes, apache-camel

I have a route structured as follows:

The files in b2bmbFileSystem://com.abc/sftp/abc/Aggregated001 are named sequentially as: `123.dat`, `456.dat`, `789.dat`. Inside the zipped file these file names are renamed to machine IDs. Is there anyway by which we can retain the filenames?

```
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<route id="com.abc.zipFile001" autoStartup="false">
    <from uri="b2bmbFileSystem://com.abc/sftp/abc/Aggregated001"/>
    <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
    <choice id="textZipFile">
        <when>
            <simple>$simple{header.CamelFileName} regex '^.*(dat|DAT)$'</simple>
            <aggregate strategyRef="zipAggregationStrategy" completionFromBatchConsumer="true" eagerCheckCompletion="true">
                <correlationExpression>
                    <constant>true</constant>
                </correlationExpression>
                <setHeader headerName="CamelFileName">
                <simple>${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ssSSS}-ZIPFILES.zip</simple>
                </setHeader>
                <to uri="b2bmbFileSystem://com.abc/sftp/abc/shipmentRequestAggregatedPGH"/>
            </aggregate>
        </when>
    </choice>
</route>
</routes>
```

Answer (score 1):

See `ZipAggregationStrategy` constructor option `useFilenameHeader`.

From [Javadoc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-zipfile/3.0.0-RC3/org/apache/camel/processor/aggregate/zipfile/ZipAggregationStrategy.html):

> useFilenameHeader - if true, the filename header will be used to name aggregated byte arrays within the ZIP file.

In Spring XML configuration you can define your `zipAggregationStrategy` bean this way:

```
<bean id="zipAggregationStrategy" class="org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.zipfile.ZipAggregationStrategy">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="false"/> <!-- preserveFolderStructure -->
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="true"/> <!-- useFilenameHeader -->
</bean>
```